# Discrete logarithm tables for the fields $\Bbb{F}_8$ and $\Bbb{F}_{16}$.

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, finite-fields

The smallest non-trivial finite field of characteristic two is
$$
\Bbb{F}_4=\{0,1,\beta,\beta+1=\beta^2\},
$$
where $\beta$ and $\beta+1$ are primitive cubic roots of unity, and zeros of the
polynomial $x^2+x+1$. Here the multiplication table is given once we know
how to write the non-zero elements as powers of $\beta$. Extend the idea to fields of eight and sixteen elements.

Those fields can be constructed as
$$
\Bbb{F}_8=\Bbb{F}_2[\alpha], \quad\text{and}\quad \Bbb{F}_{16}=\Bbb{F}_2[\gamma],
$$
where $\alpha$ has minimal polynomial $x^3+x+1$, and $\gamma$ has minimal polynomial $x^4+x+1$, both irreducible in $\Bbb{F}_2[x]$.

Task:

> Calculate the tables for base $\alpha$ discrete logarithm of $\Bbb{F}_8$ and base $\gamma$ discrete logarithm of $\Bbb{F}_{16}$.

Comment: A related [meta-thread](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/11874/11619). It may be best to discuss eventual objections to this thread there.

Comment: All: The purpose of this Q/A pair is to give an on-site explanation of the use of discrete logarithms in certain finite fields of charactertistic two, and examples of their use. I refer to this question in the [tag wiki](http://math.stackexchange.com/tags/finite-fields/info). The earlier versions of using discrete log are buried in answers to coding theoretical questions and such. My hope is that a standalone Q/A will be more accessible to the interested readers.

Comment: Jyrki, have you seen this? http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-3-642-55220-5_1

Answer (score 32, accepted):

A (base-$g$) discrete logarithm of a finite field $\Bbb{F}_q$, is a function
$$
\log_g:\Bbb{F}_q^*\to\Bbb{Z}_{q-1}
$$
defined via the equivalence $g^j=x\Leftrightarrow \log_g(x)=j$. For this to be well-defined it is imperative that $g$ is a *primitive element*, i.e. a generator of $\Bbb{F}_q^*$, and that the domain of $\log_g$ is the
residue class ring of integer modulo $q-1$, as $g^{q-1}=g^0=1$.

It immediately follows that the discrete logarithm satisfies the familiar rules
$$
\begin{aligned}
\log_g(x\cdot y)&=\log_g(x)+\log_g(y),\\
\log_g(x^n)&=n\cdot\log_g(x)
\end{aligned}
$$
for all elements $x,y\in \Bbb{F}_q^*$ and all integers $n$. The arithmetic
on the r.h.s. is that of the ring $\Bbb{Z}_{q-1}$.

---

It is known that when $q=8$, a zero $\alpha$ of $x^3+x+1$ generates $\Bbb{F}_8^*$. This is proven by the following calculation, where we repeatedly
use the fact that we are working in characteristic two, and that we have the
relation $\alpha^3=\alpha+1$.
$$
\eqalign{
\alpha^0&=&&=1,\\
\alpha^1&=&&=\alpha,\\
\alpha^2&=&&=\alpha^2,\\
\alpha^3&=&&=1+\alpha,\\
\alpha^4&=&\alpha\cdot\alpha^3=\alpha(1+\alpha)&=\alpha+\alpha^2,\\
\alpha^5&=&\alpha\cdot\alpha^4=\alpha(\alpha+\alpha^2)=\alpha^2+\alpha^3=\alpha^2+(1+\alpha)&=1+\alpha+\alpha^2,\\
\alpha^6&=&\alpha\cdot\alpha^5=\alpha(1+\alpha+\alpha^2)=\alpha+\alpha^2+\alpha^3=
\alpha+\alpha^2+(1+\alpha)&=1+\alpha^2,\\
\alpha^7&=&\alpha\cdot\alpha^6=\alpha(1+\alpha^2)=\alpha+\alpha^3=\alpha+(1+\alpha)&=1.
}$$

We see from the end results in the last column that all the non-zero
quadratic polynomials evaluated at $\alpha$ appear. This is yet another confirmation of the fact that $\alpha$ is a primitive element.

The discrete logarithm is used to replace the cumbersome multiplication (and raising
to an integer power) of the field with more familiar integer arithmetic. Exactly like the old-timers used logarithm tables to replace the error-prone multiplication with the easier addition.

For example
$$
(1+\alpha)(1+\alpha+\alpha^2)=\alpha^3\cdot\alpha^5=\alpha^8=\alpha^7\cdot\alpha=\alpha.
$$
Note that both the base-$\alpha$ discrete logarithms and its inverse mapping are needed. I generate such a table as a part of the program initialization, whenever I carry out extensive computer-aided calculations involving a finite field. The above table gives the discrete logarithm when read from right to left, and the inverse mapping (that we actually produced above) when read from left to right.

---

Similarly with $q=16$ we use $\gamma$, a zero of $x^4+x+1$. This time the table looks like
$$
\begin{aligned}
\gamma^0&=&1\\
\gamma^1&=&\gamma\\
\gamma^2&=&\gamma^2\\
\gamma^3&=&\gamma^3\\
\gamma^4&=&\gamma+1\\
\gamma^5&=\gamma(\gamma+1)=&\gamma^2+\gamma\\
\gamma^6&=\gamma(\gamma^2+\gamma)=&\gamma^3+\gamma^2\\
\gamma^7&=\gamma^4+\gamma^3=&\gamma^3+\gamma+1\\
\gamma^8&=(\gamma^4)^2=&\gamma^2+1\\
\gamma^9&=\gamma(\gamma^2+1)=&\gamma^3+\gamma\\
\gamma^{10}&=\gamma^4+\gamma^2=&\gamma^2+\gamma+1\\
\gamma^{11}&=&\gamma^3+\gamma^2+\gamma\\
\gamma^{12}&=\gamma^4+\gamma^3+\gamma^2=&\gamma^3+\gamma^2+\gamma+1\\
\gamma^{13}&=\gamma^4+\gamma^3+\gamma^2+\gamma=&\gamma^3+\gamma^2+1\\
\gamma^{14}&=\gamma^4+\gamma^3+\gamma=&\gamma^3+1\\
(\gamma^{15}&=\gamma^4+\gamma=&1)
\end{aligned}
$$

Thus for example
$$
(\gamma^3+1)(\gamma^2+1)=\gamma^{14}\cdot\gamma^8=\gamma^{22}=\gamma^7=\gamma^3+\gamma+1.
$$

---

As another example of the use of this table I want to discuss the problem of factorizing $x^4+x+1$ over $\Bbb{F}_4$. To that end we need to first identify a copy of $\Bbb{F}_4$ as a subfield of $\Bbb{F}_{16}$. We just saw that $\gamma$ is of order fifteen. Therefore $\gamma^5=\gamma^2+\gamma$ and $\gamma^{10}=\gamma^2+\gamma+1$ are third roots of unity. It is then trivial to check that we have a homomorphism of fields $\sigma:\Bbb{F}_4\to\Bbb{F}_{16}$ given by $\sigma(\beta)=\gamma^5$. Note that composing this (from either end) by the Frobenius automorphism gives an alternative embedding $\beta\mapsto \gamma^{10}$.

Basic Galois theory tells us that
$$
x^4+x+1=(x-\gamma)(x-\gamma^2)(x-\gamma^4)(x-\gamma^8)
$$
as we get the other roots by repeatedly applying the Frobenius automorphism $F:x\mapsto x^2$. Here we see that the factor 
$$
(x-\gamma)(x-\gamma^4)=x^2+x(\gamma+\gamma^4)+\gamma^5=x^2+x+\gamma^5
$$
is stable under the automorphism $F^2$, and thus (as we also see directly!) has its
coefficients in the subfield $\sigma(\Bbb{F}_4)$. The same holds for the remaining factor
$$
(x-\gamma^2)(x-\gamma^8)=x^2+x(\gamma^2+\gamma^8)+\gamma^{10}=x^2+x+\gamma^{10}.
$$
Pulling back the effect of $\sigma$ we get the desired factorization
$$
x^4+x+1=(x^2+x+\beta)(x^2+x+\beta+1)
$$
in $\Bbb{F}_4[x]$.

---

[Here is a local version of similar tables for $\Bbb{F}_{256}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2879495/11619)